# Cómo puedo hacer para que el símbolo de # se borre de la URL de swagger ui?

Tags: webservice, spring-boot, maven, swagger

[image: Quiero que el símbolo de # se borre pero cuando lo quito de la URL me sale error y no carga la ui de swagger]

Quiero que el símbolo de # se borre pero cuando lo quito de la URL me sale error y no carga la ui de swagger.
Alguien una solución, estoy usando la spring tool suite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes crear una archivo llamado SwaggerConfig para la configuracion de swagger

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.example.demo.controller"))
                .paths(Predicates.or(PathSelectors.regex("/nombreController.*")))
                        .build()
                        .apiInfo(metaData());
    }

    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Spring Boot REST API")
                .description("\"Spring Boot REST API for Online Store\"")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0\"")
                .contact(new Contact("", "", ""))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

ahora para que lo puedas borrar o modificar la url de swagger seria en esta parte

```
@Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
```

Comment: Gracias compañero develop, voy a probarlo, pero viendo la lógica de seguro si corre, gracias.

Comment: @Lukaz si mi respuesta soluciono tu problema, deberias marcarla como "respuesta correcta"